# English mail displays Chinese characters in some email clients

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an application sending english and/or czech emails, which display correctly in some emai clients (Outlook 2010) but display as a bunch of chinese characters in other. I am setting the `message.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode`, however it seems I should do something more... but it seems I don't know what :) any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Try `message.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;`?

Comment: Yes, that worked. Wonder why that didn't occur to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404377(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404377%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), try using UTF8 encoding like so:

```
message.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

Comment: I wonder why this only works when using full System.Text.Encoding.UTF8 and not when using just Encoding.UTF8.